# Why is Thor's hammer blue in his Age of Ultron poster?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, thor-marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

I saw some of the posters for *Avengers: Age of Ultron* recently, and one was of Thor holding his hammer. Now, intriguingly, his hammer is shown blue as in the picture below:

[image]

It appears like the Tesseract has fused itself with the hammer or something like that. Does this relate to the comics or something to do with Thor : The Dark World or something else entirely?

**Why is it blue?**

Comment: I don't recall any color-changing hammers in *Thor: The Dark World*.

Comment: Great. Cause i thought people'll start bombarding me saying, "You should have watched *The Dark World* before coming here." Thank God

Comment: The real hammer was unavailable, so they grabbed [one of these nightlights](http://www.gadgetreview.com/2013/06/thor-night-light-hammer).

Comment: @EdmDroid thank, *"Thor"*

Comment: In Tomb Raider Underworld, Lara Croft throws Thors Hammer into a blue river! I think this is the correct answer :D (Na, just kidding)

Comment: When Hulk can't pick up Thor's hammer, how can Lara Croft? ;D

Comment: I'm tempted to close this; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates

Comment: This is not based on any rumours. This is the poster right in front of you. And the blue color is clearly visible. So I just wanted to know whether there is a mention of a blue hammer in the comic

Comment: @EdmDroid - Hmm. The comics are not the same continuity as the movies.

Comment: Yeah but all the MCU movies do relate to comics don't they? So I just thought that this blue hammer must be somewhere in the comics which enthusiasts must have read

Comment: @Richard nothing in that meta is related to this question, put away your mod hammer

Comment: @Richard The policy you're wanting to refer to is [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based).

Comment: @phantom42 - That works too. In this case, he's made it wide enough that it's also about the comics. As such it's ok + on-topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot phantom42 cde and Richard for all the clarifications. It's really good to have people like you in the community

Comment: Since Hollywood has a habit of colorizing video and posters blue and orange? http://priceonomics.com/why-every-movie-looks-sort-of-orange-and-blue/

Comment: I would be too, if my man was constantly drooling over Natalie Portman instead of paying attention to me.

Comment: Is it just me or is Thor's expression really strange? His eyes don't look right. When I first saw this image, I thought it was a model rather than Chris Hemsworth himself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To start with, this coloring is likely *just* for the benefit of the poster, as those often have no real resemblance to the final movie, apart from having the same actors. In particular, as @Richard points out, these posters are not stills or modified stills, they were drawn by an artist to "represent" the characters from the movie. I would not put too much stock in the imagery, since it was likely chosen because the artist liked it and it looked cool.

As far as what the glow is supposed to represent, to me, this image strongly resembles the imagery for an early *Thor: The Dark World* poster:

[image: Thor: The Dark World calling lightning poster]

The blue glow is the same color as the SFX lightning being channeled through the hammer; though the hammer itself isn't completely aglow. I suspect that's the kind of image the *Avengers: Age of Ultron* Thor poster is going for: the hammer is glowing with magical energy from being used to throw lightning.

You'll note that the hammer's glow effect looks very similar to both the Tesseract and Loki's scepter, both of which we know are Infinity Stones, which IMO marks that glow as a "generic blue energy effect."

Lastly, I'll point out that a similar coloring effect is found in the Black Widow and Iron Man posters in the same series. Most likely this was just a visual element the artist liked, that thematically fit with other similar effects from the MCU, and so was used use to represent "generic plasma-ish energy".

[image: Avengers: Age of Ultron Black Widow Poster]

Comment: You may also want to note that the image is consistent with others in the same series; http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-97DtZMw24EM/VNnVHjcj7XI/AAAAAAAAVD0/32gtSgRt7ls/s1600/Avengers_Age_Of_Ultron_009.jpg

Comment: good call, I didn't catch that originally.

Comment: are they cutaway panels? or is it extra stitching to help with the strain?

Comment: Oh my. I'll be in my bunk.

Comment: Sometimes those posters aren't even the same actor. I remember Keira Knightley being a bit miffed at finding she suddenly had bust on one of the "King Arthur" posters after being *cast* for having a figure suitable for an archeress... :-D

Comment: @DevSolar that was still her on the poster. They airbrushed the picture to give the impression of a bigger bustline.

Comment: Leading actors are expensive. It's much cheaper to pay a nobody body double for the photo shoot and photoshop the actor's head on later. Unfortunately this tends to look fake and they do take more than a few liberties with reality.